# When there are four aveilim (mourners), Is it better to have one minyan of 40 people or 4 minyonim of ten each?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, mourning-aveilus, tzibur-community

Today I was in a shul where there were four parallel mincha services because four mourners wanted to lead the services. I thought there was a principle of ברב עם הדרת מלך?

What sources are there that discuss this issue and what do they say?

Comment: Was there no Rav?

Comment: @SethJ No Rav present. (Do you mean that the Rav should not have allowed it??) I was once told that the shul was founded on the condition that multiple minyonim were allowed.

Comment: I meant that the Rav could have explained why he allowed it (if, indeed, he had).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rav Moshe Feinstein ([Igrot Moshe YD 4:61:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=339)) ruled they should not split up because of BeRov Am, and all the more so in a case where the extra group would not be in a Shul or even a room without a Torah scroll.

Rav Chaim Kanievsky ([Gam Ani Odekha (Shonim) 3:34](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48357&st=&pgnum=18)) says it is better in your situation not to split up into multiple Minyanim.

Rav Yehuda Herzl Henkin ([Benei Vanim 2:1 (footnote)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=11)) complains about those who split off into the hallways to make extra Minyanim for this purpose.

Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Halikhot Shlomo 5:1) writes that while it is technically permitted to split into multiple Minyanim if each will be held in an organized and respectable fashion, if reasonably possible it should be avoided. Rav Yitzchak Yosef ([Kitzur Yalkut Yosef Avelut](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_65.html) 31:8) rules accordingly.

Rav Yitzchak Yaakov Weiss ([Minchat Yitzchak 9:122](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14684&st=&pgnum=171)), brought by [ba](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569/b-a), speculates that the fact that no one suggested this a long time ago but instead debate how to split up the different Kaddishes among the different mourners implies this shouldn't be done.

Rav Chaim Oshri ([Mekor Chayim 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2455&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=)) asked this of Rav Shlomo Cohen ([Binyan Shlomo 13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4458&st=&pgnum=54)). The latter writes that he thinks it is permitted to split as there is no benefit of BeRov Am anyway nowadays when everyone prays individually and no one relies on the Chazzan, a decidedly non-standard position. Rav Oshri responds rejecting that and only permitting splitting into multiple Minyanim because of the Mitzva of doing Chesed for the deceased.

Rav Yaakov Epstein ([Chevel Nachalato 8:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%97_%D7%90)) rules that they should not split up a fixed communal Minyan on account of multiple mourners.

Rav Dovid Sperber ([Afarkasta deAnya 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=871&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=)), brought by [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/200/gershon-gold), allows splitting up at least in part based on the Taz ([OC 193 sk 3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1012)) who rules that a group of six may choose to split into two groups for a Zimmun because the extra Mitzva of Zimmun balances out the loss of BeRov Am. However, the Bach (ibid) and Rama (ibid :2) both rule that staying together is preferred. The Arukh haShulchan (OC 193:13) seems to rule like the Rama, and the Mishna Berura (ibid. sk 11) cites both opinions. So that argument is not necessarily universally agreed upon.

Rav Moshe Shternbuch ([Teshuvot veHanhagot 1:127](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=99)) ruled they should not split up into multiple Minyanim. Once though he saw that the person with the Yahrtzeit who wouldn't be able to lead the services became pained, and he ruled that it would be a Mitzva of Chesed for 9 men to give up their BeRov Am to go pray with this man, and in that merit their prayers should be accepted as if they were in a large group.

Indeed, I suspect everyone would agree in this case that [Gadol haShalom](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=65b&format=pdf), and if the mourners are unable to accept a Psak not to split (by realizing that the collective benefit of BeRov Am is more beneficial than leading prayers) and are going to fight each other, then we should certainly allow them to split, for what kind of merit is it for the deceased to have his descendant fighting another Jew?

Comment: more discussion http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46507&st=&pgnum=334

Comment: See too [Sefer HaOrah 2:59](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XHV8z.png) who implies a group of 10 men who split off from the Shul don't even count as a Minyan.

Comment: Shu"t Devar Chevron YD 548 says you shouldn't split unless that community has a specific custom to do that.

Answer (score 10):

The [Shaalos U'tshuvos Afraksa D'Anya - Siman 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=871&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=) discusses this question and concludes that each mourner may have his own Minyan.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other sources that agree or disagree?

Answer (score 5):

The Rama ([YD 376:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=378&hilite=)) says that if there are three brothers and one non-brother, they should all split four kadeishim, and the three brothers don't all say kadish at once. The Pischei Teshuvah ([YD 376:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=378&hilite=)) says that everyone should say kadish all at once. They don't specify whether they are talking about in a case where there are enough to make many minyanim.

The [Minchas Yitzchak 9:122](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14684&st=&pgnum=171) says that it seemed that they should not split up into different minyanim, but said he was in a rush and couldn't deliberate on it.