# Should people davening alone daven together?

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, minyan

If a few men know there will be no minyan so they choose to daven biyechidut, is there merit to their staying "together" either in shul or not? Is there a notion of "kahal" or "rov am" even in part if they daven "together" (maybe even with one davening out loud to set a pace)?

I have heard that when one davens alone at his home, he is supposed to daven at the same time as the [minyan](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/38708) at shul (though [this](https://anshe.org/revised-halachos-of-davening-alone/) site makes it only as a suggestion) and in this way, he sort of attaches to the group davening of the minyan and his davening is not [rejected](https://www.queensjewishlink.com/index.php/torah/63-halachic-highlights/2397-davening-at-your-regular-time). Does this "group" identity attach even when the group in shul is smaller than 10?

Comment: There is always an advantage to davening in shul, even with no one else present

Comment: We have this question I think already

Comment: I thought so too but nothing came up.

Comment: It's asked at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16209/170 but as one part of a multipart question, and that part wasn't answered, so I recommend you edit it out of that question and keep this one. I haven't time now. cc @DoubleAA

Comment: Not exactly on target, but there is a Hagaos Mimoni that one should pray with the congregation in shul even if there is not a minyan there.

Comment: @msh no we have better. I think from DanF about a shul that didn't get a minyan one morning should they still have a pseudo chazzan

Comment: I seem to remember it has to do with how many people at kiddush levono.

Comment: Do you mean "together" as opposed to "go away" or "together in shul" or "simultaneously"? Let me ask it differently, say we have 7 friends on a hiking trekk. Should we daven at once or each one can find his own time?

Comment: Together would indicate at least the same place and starting at the same time but could even be "following the vocalilzed pace of on person"

Comment: There is some rational for answering yes to this question. if all the people know each other , then participants are less likely to miss a tefillah since they're expecting you to show up. And even if people do not know each other it's more of a motivation to get you to join the group.

Comment: should women be encouraged to daven with other women if they are not going to shul?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does all or nothing apply to a minyan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/122412/does-all-or-nothing-apply-to-a-minyan)

Comment: Obviously it doesn't count for a minyan, but I've heard there's value in even 3 davening together.