# rov am hadras melech by koton?

Tags: halacha, minyan, minor-katan-child, rov-am

Is there an idea of rov am hadras melech (a larger group of people is greater glory for the King) for a minor or anybody else who would be exempt from a mitzva like praying with a minyan (quorum)? Meaning, would it be better for them to pray together, or would it not matter? Sourced answers only please.

Note that this question specifically isn’t about chinuch (training minors to do mitzvas).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters for brov am?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20709/parameters-for-brov-am) which also asks about its application to children.

Comment: @DonielF the question is the same, but there is no sourced answer that answers my question.

Comment: Please define "better" Halachicly if not by Chinuch.

Comment: @Loani So, this *is* an exact duplicate then? I know you don’t have enough rep to post a bounty yet, but that’s what the next step would be, rather than posting the question again. Do you want me to post a bounty for you?

Comment: Would it be better because of rov am hadras melech, or only because of chinuch? A nafka Mina: If chinuch is was the only reason, 20 kids could split up into 2 minyanim. If rov am is also a reason, they couldn’t.

Comment: Sure DonielF. Just please make sure to note that the bounty is not for the last part of the question, which was answered already. Shkoyach!

Comment: @Doniel if that q has multiple parts and this asks a unanswered part, better to just edit it out of there and let this question stand, thereby splitting the questions up.

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA but for now, unless and until someone edits the other question, I've temporarily closed this one to answers so not both questions attract the same answers.